# z-index not working with absolute positioning of elements

Tags: html, css

I am creating a component like the stacked cards, I am having all cards positioning as absolute but facing issues with z-index property, The cards doesn't seem to change with respect to z-index.

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;position:relative">
  <div style="height:180px;width:280px;background-color:green;position:absolute;top:70px;z-index:100;box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px black"/>
    <div style="height:180px;width:260px;background-color:blue;position:absolute;top:-20px;z-index:99;left:10px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black"/>
      <div style="height:180px;width:240px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:-20px;z-index:98;left:10px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black"/>
        <div style="height:180px;width:220px;background-color:yellow;position:absolute;top:-20px;z-index:97;left:10px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening? And btw, divs aren't self-closing

Comment: floating of cards order is not changing when I change the z-index values

Comment: You can't self-close divs with `/>` so the browser fixes it and nests them all. When it does that your z-index becomes irrelevant as the child can't appear higher than the parent.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: `<div ......  />` is invalid. you should use `<div ...... ></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div closure is wrong, but so is the positioning. Take out the left and make the top go up by the number of pixels that you want overlapped.

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;position:relative">
  <div style="height:180px;width:280px;background-color:green;position:absolute;top:70px;z-index:100;box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px black"></div>
  <div style="height:180px;width:260px;background-color:blue;position:absolute;top:65px;z-index:99;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black"></div>
  <div style="height:180px;width:240px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:60px;z-index:98;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black"></div>
  <div style="height:180px;width:220px;background-color:yellow;position:absolute;top:55px;z-index:97;box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px black"></div>
</div>
```